# How to integrate a Tensorflow RNN (LSTM/GRU) with pre-trained embeddings into a mobile device (android/iphone)?

Tags: android, python, ios, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have developed a model, for classification which used pre-trained glove embeddings on Wikipedia, as the lookup table for words in a sentence. As the size of this embedding is large (around `2.5GB`), I am passing it as a placeholder rather than a variable.

`EMBEDDING_MATRIX = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, embedding_dimension], name='EMBEDDING_MATRIX')`

While training, I am passing that value as feed dict.

`embeddings = np.load('glove_wiki.npy')
feed_dict = {EMBEDDING_MATRIX: embeddings}`.

Now, I have a created a `.pb` format of the model, using tensorflow freezing. Things are good in computer. 
Now, I want to integrate this model into tensorflow lite and I know, `.pb` is the way to go for it. But, how will I use this huge size glove embeddings in a mobile device? That is not possible right. So, I was wondering if there any solution for this. I believe, most of the latest models are more advanced and they are also using word embeddings as a lookup table. Rather, than provide this model as an API in the cloud, how can I integrate this into a mobile device. Because Google smart reply is also using LSTM model I guess. Any suggestions will be appreciated.